# Need help troubleshooting USB disk automount

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd

It is an USB3 disk I try to automount, but it is not working.

> /etc/fstab

UUID=8EBA6FE9BA6FCC71 /home/plex/ext ntfs-3g user,umask=000,utf8,flush,noauto 0 0

[image: This after a reboot]

```
plex@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -l /home/plex/ext
[sudo] password for plex:
total 105952
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28672 Oct 24 19:36 _Apps
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root         0 Sep 30 21:00 msdownld.tmp
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4096 Dec 27 21:15 Musikk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 108445778 Dec 13 15:34 plexmediaserver_1.10.1.4602-
f54242b6b_amd64.deb
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4096 Sep 30 20:10 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4096 Oct  1  2016 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4096 Dec 28 18:30 The.Universe



plex@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -ld /home/plex/ext
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 16:32 /home/plex/ext
```

Comment: It seems to me, that the partition was already mounted. Maybe the problem is that your user has no access, only root (the superuser) has access. Please run the following command, after reboot, when the line in `/etc/fstab` has been used to mount the partition, `sudo ls -l /home/plex/ext` and `sudo ls -ld /home/plex/ext` and edit your original question to show the result. Please copy and paste the text from the terminal window, and indent each line 4 spaces to render it as 'code'.

Comment: The owner is `root`, and there are read/write/execute permissions for owner/group/others. This means that it should be possible for you (your user ID) to have full access to files in `/home/plex/ext`. You could change the ownership (and keep the group) with the following command, `sudo chown $USER /home/plex/ext` and change the owner also for files and directories in the directory tree with `sudo chown -R $USER /home/plex/ext` but I am not sure if it will make any significant difference in your case.

Comment: Please notice that the mount option `noauto` in `/etc/fstab` means that it will *not* be automatically mounted, but it will be easy to mount according to the settings in `/etc/fstab`. ( `noauto` is useful for partitions that are not always connected, typical for external drives.) `sudo mount /home/plex/ext` and even `mount /home/plex/ext` (by the user ID, with the mount option 'user').